# What hashes are common hashes? used on the net and other programs?

Tags: hash

I seen MD5 and SHA1 hashes on the net to verify files. What are common hashes used on the net and other programs? This is to verify a file not to hash a pw.

Answer (score 17):

I've used some hash functions from the following site before - they are usually pretty quick, and full code is given on the website, and a description of each of the functions and their strengths/weaknesses:

[http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions](http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/)

Examples of the hashes given are - Kernighan and Ritchie (from "The C Programming Language") and the Knuth hash (from "The Art Of Computer Programming Volume 3").

Answer (score 3):

To verify files you can use [cyclic redundancy checks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check), such as CRC32, which have been as far as I know the de-facto standard for hashing files for a long time in the IT, if you want to look at other stuff than MD5/SHA.

See also this [list of checksum algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) for more ways to check your files.

Comment: CRC32 is no de-facto anymore.. it's very ancient! SHA & MD5 are more used for hashing files these days.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Intel added a CRC32 instruction to SSE 4.2 so CRC lives on.

Comment: @Hank Gay, crc32 is still used for certain low level protocols and is still useful, but not for files anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I never used anything else than MD5. Add a Salt if you use it for passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a [list of hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions), broken up into different types (checksums, non-crypto, crypto etc).

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Foundation (among others) uses [PGP Signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#Digital_signatures).